# Jquery load php script each 10th second

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How do i make jquery load a php script each 10th second until the php script returns a value which is not empty? (Then it should stop loading the php script)

Comment: Yes. I realize that :) it's passing the varibles to jquery from the scripts which is being run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) will take care of this for you.